# Docker containers, memory consumption and logs

Tags: mysql, memory, docker, mariadb, docker-compose

I've been trying Docker for a few days. I'm using a Drupal image (docker4drupal) which basically contains MySQL (MariaDB), PHP (php-fpm) and NGINX.

Almost everytime I do a database import to the database container, on a VPS with 512MB RAM, the container with MariaDB dies... and messages like "MySQL server has gone away" appear... And this does not happen when my VPS has 1GB o 2GB RAM.

So, this seems to be a memory problem, but I need the evidence! I don't know where is the log that tells me that my container died because wasn't enough memory.

I checked MariaDB logs but I can't find anything... it's log only say somethign like "the database was not normally shutdown" and thaen "it's starting" and then "wating for connections"...

So, independently of my MariaDB config (which is not proper for a 512MB VPS)...  Where can I find explicitly the reason of why the container with the database server died?

Any help is welcome.
Thanks a lot.

PD: I execute mysql cli from the PHP container, that's why despite the database container dies I still can see the output that something wrong happened.

Comment: Could be the kernel terminating most memory-consuming process on 'lack-of-memory' event. Some entries may be there in host system log. Lack of such entries doesn't guarantee it wasn't kernel who killed your DB, though

Comment: Thanks @agg3l Is it on kern.log? I think I'm looking at the error but I'm not sure...

Comment: Exact filename depends on host system configuration (meaning the VPS, in your case). Could be /var/log/{system.log,error.log, ...}. _kern.log_ is a reasonable place to write log entries emitted by kernel as well

Comment: Thanks @agg3l! I think I found it! It's Out of memory: Kill process 4723 (mysqld) score 328 or sacrifice child. In fact are multiple of these lines :D (I'm in dev, if I were in production I would not be happy jaja)

Comment: If you answer with your first comment I will check it as the best answer. If not I will answer myself. As you wish.

Comment: You're welcome. Those entries you've found reside in host logs, correct? (I'm not absolutely sure where can land in general case, but I assume it's host from my understanding how docker works)

Comment: I did this: grep -rnw '/var/log/' -e 'Out of memory'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be the kernel terminating most memory-consuming process on 'lack-of-memory' event. Some entries may be there in host system log. Lack of such entries doesn't guarantee it wasn't kernel who killed your DB, though.

Exact filename depends on host system configuration (meaning the VPS, in your case). Could be /var/log/{system.log,error.log, ...}.

As long as docker container is not an isolated VM but a wrapper over kernel-driven cgroups, kernel events are handled by host system loggin daemon

Answer (score 1):

Hi Beto we can see the logs in docker checkout the below commands:

The docker logs --follow command will continue streaming the new output from the container’s STDOUT and STDERR.

Comment: Hi @Vishnu! Thanks for the reply. So, if my docker container is called mariadb, how could I obtainer it's log with the reason of it's dead? (sorry if the answer seems obvious but I'm a bit confused)

Comment: docker logs --follow mariadb // should give you the logs try and let me know if you have any issues

Comment: You were right, those are the logs of the container, but these logs does not tell me anything of what happened... not in this case at least. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably too much to cram in a minuscule 512MB.  Do one of

- Increase RAM available.  ("And this does not happen when my VPS has 1GB")
- Split applications across multiple tiny Dockers.
- Tune each app to use less RAM.  (Didn't I answer your question recently?)

How many tables do you have?  Hopefully not a lot, as in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60888/mysql-runs-out-of-memory-when-importing-innodb-database

Comment: Thanks Rick. RAM was the problem, no doubt about it... but I needed the explicit evidence, which I found in the kernel Logs.

Comment: I made a similar question recently.